# Create condition when session storage should work

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below. This causes a message to appear when the window is in portrait mode. When the "X" is clicked, the message disappears and does not return within the same session.

This works well, however, when the window is refreshed/reloaded before even clicking the "X", the message should still appear when the window is sized to portrait mode. Only after the "X" is clicked should the message no longer appear within the same session.

Can you help please?

[**See Example Here!**](https://jsfiddle.net/4z9heaze/52/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('isfirst');
    if (data == undefined) {
        $("#warning-message").addClass("shown-modal");
        sessionStorage.setItem('isfirst', 'true');
    } else {
        $("#warning-message").hide();
    }
});
//close the pop
$("#landscape-button").on('click', function() {
    $("#warning-message").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the session variable to be set after clicking on 'X', you should simply move `sessionStorage.setItem('isfirst', 'true');` inside the on click function of `#landscape-button`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('isfirst');
    if (data == undefined) {
        $("#warning-message").addClass("shown-modal");
    } else {
        $("#warning-message").hide();
    }
});
//close the pop
$("#landscape-button").on('click', function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('isfirst', 'true');
    $("#warning-message").hide();
});
```